# What does $(a+b) \bmod{256}$ and $a$ XOR $b$ reveal about $a, b$?

Tags: cryptanalysis, entropy, xor

Say $a$ and $b$ are some uniform random $8$ bits so that the entropy of $a$ and $b$ is 8 bits each.

If I show you $(a+b) \bmod{256}$ and $a$ XOR $b$, then what can you tell about $a$ and $b$?  Or how much of their entropy is reduced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume bitstrings are assimilated to integers by big-endian notation, $a$ and $b$ are $k$-bits with $k=8$ in the question, and it's given two $k$-bit quantities $s:=a+b\bmod{2^k}$ and $x:=a\oplus b$.

$s$ and $x$ are not independent: their low-order bit is the same. Therefore revealing $(s,x)$ reveals *at most* $2k-1$ bit of information, thus cause *at most* a $2k-1$ bit reduction of entropy.

Since given $a$ and $x$ we can compute $b=a\oplus x$, revealing $(s,x)$  cause *at least* a $k$ bit reduction of entropy.

The actual reduction of entropy varies between these bounds:

- With $x=0$ and $s$ even, the solutions are $(a,b)\in\{(s/2,s/2),(s/2+2^{k-1},s/2+2^{k-1})\}$, thus there remains $\log_2(2)=1$ bit of entropy out of the initial $2k$, a loss of $2k-1$ bits of entropy.
- With $x=s=1$ there are 4 solutions: $(a,b)\in\{(0,1),(1,0),(2^{k-1},2^{k-1}+1),(2^{k-1}+1,2^{k-1})\}$, thus there remains $\log_2(4)=2$ bit of entropy out of the initial $2k$, a loss of $2k-2$ bits of entropy.
- With $x=s=2^{k-1}$ there are $2^k$ solutions of the form $(a,2^k-1-a)$, thus there remains $k$ bit of entropy out of the initial $2k$, a loss of $k$ bits of entropy.

I assert without proof that for $i\in[0,k)$ the entropy loss is $2k-1-i$ bit with probability ${k-1\choose i}/2^{k-1}$, and that it follows the expected entropy loss is $(3k-1)/2$ bit.

Answer (score 5):

fgrieu analyzes the average case; we can also consider the worst case - how much the entropy are we guaranteed to have left.

One 'worse case' happens if the $a+b = 0 \pmod {256}$ and $a \oplus b = 0$; in that case, the only possible solutions are $a=b=0$ and $a=b=128$; hence we have reduced the entropy to 1 bit.

More generally, this worse case happens if $a \oplus b = 0$ or $a \oplus b = 128$; whenever that happens, there are only two possible solutions, namely (in the case of $a \oplus b = 0$, we have either $a = b = sum/2$ (where $sum$ is the published sum, which will always be even) or $a = b = sum/2 + 128$; in the case of $a \oplus b = 128$, we have $a, b = sum/2, sum/2 + 128$ in some order.

We note that, for any $a, b$, the alternative values $a \oplus 128, b \oplus 128$ always give the same xor and sum, hence there are always at least two solutions - hence this bad case is the worse case.

Answer (score 4):

As I didn't see it mentioned yet: $a + b = (a\oplus b) + ((a\&b)<<1) \bmod 256$ (where $<<$ denotes left-shift), so the information you are given is equivalent to knowing $a\oplus b$ and - except the highest bit - $a\&b$.

All functions $a+b$, $a\oplus b$ and $a\&b$ are symmetric in $a$ and $b$. For a fixed bit position $i$ you can therefore at most know how many of the two bits $a_i$ and $b_i$ are 1, but if it's only one, then you don't know which one.

For all but the highest bits you know $a_i\&b_i$ and $a_i\oplus b_i$, which are just the binary digits of $a_i+b_i$, so you have for every bit position (but the highest) exactly the 0/1-count. For the highest bit position you just have $a_7\oplus b_7$.

From this you should be able to derive the results of poncho and fgrieu.