# For any numbers $a, b$, what are the operators $X, Y$ such that revealing $a\ X\ b$ and $a\ Y\ b$ doesn't reveal info about $a,b$?

Tags: cryptanalysis, entropy

[Previously](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/99849) I thought about a pair of 8-bit uniformly distributed random numbers $(a,b) \in \{0,1\}^8$, and $X$ to be bitwise XOR, $Y$ to be 8-bit addition.  But it turned out that revealing $a \text{ XOR } b, a+b \bmod{2^8}$ does reveal a lot of information bits about $a,b$.

[A smart dude here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/99851/30728) mentioned "dependence" as a property.  So I guess I am looking for independent operators?  Or, at least, operators that are independent when their input are random numbers?

My questions are:

- How far can we go in minimising the amount of information that $a\ X\ b$ and $a\ Y\ b$ give about $a,b$?
- Can we mathematically prove any bounds?  E.g. proving that if $a,b$ are uniform random numbers, then if $X$ is ... and $Y$ is ..., then it has to be that $a\ X\ b$ and $a\ Y\ b$ cannot give more than $x$ bits of information about $a,b$?

Comment: If $X$ (resp. $Y$) can take $u$ (resp. $v$) values over the full set of it's two arguments, then $a\ X\ b$ and $a\ Y\ b$ together can't take more than $u\,v$ values, thus can't reveal more than $\log_2(u\,v)$ bit of information. A better bound is possible for some choice of $X$ and $Y$ making the values "dependent" , but I don't know how to characterize that better than defining the dependency as the difference between that bound and the actual amount of information disclosed,

Comment: @fgrieu - Trying to understand: if we only deal with 8-bit variables, then will that mean that $u=v=8$?  Also, any idea how to prove the $\log_2(uv)$ bound?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ depend on $X$ and $Y$. If we define $a\ X\ b $ and $a\ Y\ b $ to be 42 regardless of $a$ and $b$, then $u=v=1$, $\log_2(u\,v)$ is $0$, and thus this upper bound tells us that no information is revealed about $a$ and $b$. Notice that when $a\ X\ b $ and $a\ Y\ b $ are non-constant but equal regardless of $a$ and $b$, we have $u=v>1$, the bound $\log_2(u\,v)$ holds but is loose. Proof of the $\log_2(u\,v)$ bound: a variable taking $w$ values can't reveal more than $\log_2(w)$ bit of information, and for $(X,Y)$ we get at most $w=u\,v$ values.

Comment: I'm wondering: are you considering "the amount of information that $a\ X\ b$ and $a\ Y\ b$ give about $a,b$" (which can be up to always 16 bits, assuming e.g. $a\ X\ b$ returns $a$, and $a\ Y\ b$ returns $b$), or the amount of information that $a\ X\ b$ and $a\ Y\ b$ give about one of $a$ or $b$, the other being regarded as random and unknown (obviously that can't exceed 8 bits)?

Comment: @fgrieu  The former.  Both $a,b$ are supposed to be secrets as much as possible.  I'm trying to find how far can one go with operators $X,Y$ in terms of minimising information leakage off $a,b$.  I see why $\log_2(uv)$ is a loose maximum bound (because this is the maximum information containable in $uv$ many unique numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to leak zero information. Assume uniformly distributed $a$ and $b$ and let $a$ vary along the rows and $b$ along the columns of the operation tables below:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
X & 0&1&2&3\\ \hline
0 & 0&1&2&3 \\
1 & 1&2&3&0 \\
2 & 2&3&0&1 \\
3 & 3&0&1&2
\end{array} & \quad &
\begin{array}{l|cccc}
Y & 0&1&2&3\\ \hline
0 & 3&0&1&2 \\
1 & 0&1&2&3 \\
2 & 1&2&3&0 \\
3 & 2&3&0&1
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Note that for each operation knowing the output ($aXb$ or $aYb$) gives no information at all about $a$. The same is true of $b$. But if you know one of $a$ or $b$ you then know the other one uniquely.

Furthermore, let us say $aXb=0.$ The possible pairs $(a,b)$ are now in the set
$$
S=\{(0,0),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\}.
$$

Assuming no errors in computing the operation, the only possibility for $aYb$ is $aYb=3$ and this gives *no further information* about the possible pairs in $S$.

You may say this is a strange example, but it demonstrates that the minimum can be zero for each individual input variable.

One last point, since I don't know your requirements exactly. It is possible to double the bitlength of the output while ensuring even knowing one of $a$ or $b$ leaks no information about the other. The output $2X3=12$ would correspond to the output bit pattern $0110$ with $01=1,$ and $10=2.$ Here is an example below:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
X & 0&1&2&3\\ \hline
0 & 00&11&22&33 \\
1 & 13&02&31&20 \\
2 & 21&30&03&12 \\
3 & 32&23&10&01
\end{array} 
$$
Now let us say you know that $a=1.$ This restricts you to  the second row  of the operating table but $b$ is still completely undetermined, you know *nothing* about the value of $b.$

This example uses two MOLS (Mutually Orthogonal Latin Squares).

Comment: _Astounding-total-amaze-stupendousness_.  This is pure glory.  Thanks a lot.  However, I don't get the double bit-length one:  if $aXb = 12$, wouldn't it be a trivial lookup to see that it must be $a=2, b=3$?  I.e. both $a,b$ are exposed?  Perhaps I am missing something fundamental?

Comment: In the information theoretic model about information leakage we observe certain variables and ask about the uncertainty regarding the other variables once that value is known. So we observe, e.g., $aXb$ and ask about $a$ or $b$ or $a,b$ both. Alternatively we observe $a$ and $aXb$ and ask about $b$. Also, if we apply the model to a larger set in a cryptographic context, brute force is not feasible.

Comment: I'm just not able to read the last table.  $2X3 = 12$, right? But your text says $1X2=12$?

Comment: see edit for a clarification